# youtu.be instead of buffly

Tags: youtube, buffer

Is there way to use youtu.be instead of buff.ly when sharing [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/) video over [Buffer](http://bufferapp.com)?

I don't really use the tracking feature, I just use the service as a buffer for posts. Reason why I wanted this was some services do not recognize it as YouTube video when it's shortened by buff.ly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. Buffer adds their special shortened link to allow them to track clicks on their links. To get past this would involve doing manual work yourself to share videos which would defeat the purpose of Buffer. Buffer's shortening acts much like Twitter where they shorten all the URL's.

From a business standpoint tracking the URL's in this method is very effective as they are able to then determine how many people are following certain links and therefore can also give that data to the user.